# Private_pub console.log doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, private-pub

Why can't you use console.log inside a publish_to call?

`create.js.erb:`

```
<% publish_to @path do %>
    console.log("i'm here")
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can't you? What happens?

Comment: You're aware that the gem is abandoned, right?

Comment: I wasn't - it's still very good. The issue was that a JS line earlier up was failing silently, and preventing further lines of javascript from running.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that a JS line earlier up was failing silently, and preventing further lines of javascript from running